# Express version routing with semver

Tags: node.js, express, semantic-versioning

I'm using [express-routes-versioning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-routes-versioning) to version my routes.

```
app.post('/messages', authUser, routesVersioning({
    "1.0.5": function(req, res) {
        moduleMessages.addV105(req, res);
    }
}, function(req, res) {
    moduleMessages.add(req, res);
}));
```

This works fine and calls `addV105()` for version 1.0.5 and `add()` for every other version. But I want to call `addV105()` for every version which is >= 1.0.5 (1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.1.0, 2.3...) and `add()` for every version < 1.0.5 (1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.0..)

What would be the syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Fixed the missleading title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`express-routes-versioning` doesn't support a lot of semver operations/ranges, only `^` and `~`, which aren't useful for your use case.

An alternative Express middleware is [`express-semver-routing`](https://github.com/n-johnson/express-semver-routing), which is more flexible in terms of matching (it uses [`semver`](https://github.com/npm/node-semver), so you can probably use any of its comparators).

You do have to rewrite your route setup a bit:

```
const version = require('express-semver-routing')();
...
app.post('/messages', authUser, version('>= 1.0.5'), function(req, res) {
  moduleMessages.addV105(req, res);
});

app.post('/messages', authUser, function(req, res) {
  moduleMessages.add(req, res);
});
```

(I think you may want to switch `version()` and `authUser` in the first route, otherwise `authUser` will be called twice when the version doesn't match the version).

Or using the DRY principle, use a separate router:

```
let router = express.Router();

router.use(authUser)
      .post('/', version('>= 1.0.5'), function(req, res) {
        moduleMessages.addV105(req, res);
      })
      .post('/', function(req, res) {
        moduleMessages.add(req, res);
      });

app.use('/messages', router);
```

Comment: `app.post('/messages/', version('>= 1.0.5'), authUser, function (req, res)` + `curl -X POST -H "Accept-Version: 1.0.5" foo.bar/messages` ends in an error: `Error: Invalid semver value provided: [object Object]<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /var/www/21messages.com/dev/node_modules/express-semver-routing/index.js:26:46`